# "ReferenceError: getInput is not defined" in react input element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

```
class HelloWorldComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.getInput = this.getInput.bind(this)
  }
  getInput() {
    alert('focused');
  }
  render() {
    return (      
      <input type="text" onFocus={getInput}/>    
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <HelloWorldComponent/>,
  document.getElementById('react_example')
);
```

What's wrong with this code? can't get the alert to fire, I got getInput is not defined error.

http://jsbin.com/qoduyawaci/1/edit

Comment: `this.getInput = this.getInput.bind(this)` - why?

Comment: @JaromandaX why not?

Comment: Look, I may be wrong, but I would've thought that `this.getInput` doesn't need to be bound to `this` because it already is a property of `this` ... I'll admit that I can only say I'm 99% sure of how `this` works, but it just looks like odd (redundant) code to me

Comment: @JaromandaX it's needed because I use es6 syntax, try here http://jsbin.com/qozupufoja/1/edit?html,js,console,output with the code you think that should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to add the correct refference. use **this.getInput** instead of **getInput**.

like this

```
class HelloWorldComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.getInput = this.getInput.bind(this);
  }
  getInput() {
    alert('focused');
  }
  render() {
    return (      
      <input type="text" onFocus={this.getInput}/>    
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <HelloWorldComponent/>,
  document.getElementById('react_example')
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `this.getInput` instead of `getInput`

http://jsbin.com/nehadisuvu/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

Use `this.getInput` to call the function.
Also you can use arrow **functions** in **ES6** to avoid binding.

```
getInput = () => {
    alert('focused');
 }
```

and you can avoid

```
this.getInput = this.getInput.bind(this)
```

in constructor. This is the correct ES6 method.

http://jsbin.com/sebotirito/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Your first suggestion is not valid ES6. It's an experimental feature that requires additional configuration to work.

Comment: @FelixKling this.getInput is used for accessing class member function.

Comment: I never disputed that. Maybe I didn't express myself clearly. I was talking about `getInput = () => ...`.